# Using custom etc/resolv.conf for deployed virtual servers?

Tags: domain-name-system, debian, resolv.conf

Saw that cloudflare is now powering their own set of DNS servers https://developers.cloudflare.com/1.1.1.1/setting-up-1.1.1.1/linux/

We are running a couple dozen debian systems.

Anyone used a custom etc/resolv.conf on server deployments? Is it advised?

Comment: Why not give your deployed servers their DNS settings from DHCP? As i remember /etc/resolv.conf is overwritten by other scripts / programs. Personally i find it much easier to manage a DHCP service to set static IP addresses and other information needed this way

Answer (score 0):

I would only do that if your local DNS servers are deficient in some way -- either they are slow or they return "helpful" answers for queries that should return failure. Some consumer level DNS servers do that.

It is not likely that the cloudflare servers respond faster than the local ones provided by your data center.